# Calculating the maximum value of this function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I was messing around in Desmos Graphing Calculator and I input this function (graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tcnjzy93j7)):
$$
f(x) = 2^{x-1.1^{x}}
$$
I noticed it had a peak at around $(24.663, 18442.801)$, and I tried using the derivative of the function to get that value and I got this:
$$
f'(x) = 2^{x-1.1^{x}} \cdot ln(2) \cdot (1 - 1.1^{x} \cdot ln(1.1))
$$
The thing is, I don't have any idea of how to get the value of $x$ when $f'(x)=0$. Do I have to use non-conventional methods to get the value of $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing fine.  Take your derivative and set it to be equal to $0$:
$$0=2^{x-1.1^x}\cdot\log2\cdot(1-1.1^x\cdot\log1.1)$$
and notice that only the last factor has a root.  Solve the equation
\begin{align}
1-1.1^x\cdot\log1.1&=0\\
1.1^x\cdot\log1.1&=1\\
1.1^x&=\frac1{\log1.1}\\
x\cdot{\log1.1}&=\log\left(\frac1{\log1.1}\right)\\
x&=\frac{-\log\log1.1}{\log1.1}\approx24.66283
\end{align}
where $\log$ is the natural logarithm.

Comment: Oh, I somehow didn't see it. Thanks!